# Segmentation Fault when printing a linked list recursively

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've coded a linked list in C, (using gcc compiler) and tried to print it recursively. It tells "segmentation fault", and also prints the first value only. Could anyone suggest an option to correct it..? This is my code.

```
#define MAX 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void printRecursively(struct node *start) {
    if (start != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", start->value);
        start = start->next;
        printRecursively(start);
    }
}

void main() {
    struct node *nodes[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        nodes[i]->value = i + 1;
        nodes[i]->next = nodes[i + 1];
    }
    printRecursively(nodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `printRecursively` calls back to back?

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  both have a return type of `int`  (regardless of what Visual Studio might allow.)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in function `main()`, this line: `nodes[i]->next = nodes[i + 1];` is setting the 'next' field of the current node with some random value found in the next entry in the array `nodes[]`.  Random because that value has not yet been initialized via a call to `malloc()`  And the 'next' field is never set to 'NULL' so all will contain some random value.  So the recursion is very unlikely to ever end, unless due to a seg fault event, where the random value in 'next' points to some memory that the application does not own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. does not perform any undefined behavior
4. incorporates the comments to the OPs question

now, the proposed code:

```
#define MAX 10
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};


void printRecursively(struct node *start)
{
    if (start != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", start->value);
        start = start->next;
        printRecursively(start);
    }
} // end function: printRecursively


int main( void )
{
    struct node *nodes[MAX] = { NULL };

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        nodes[i]->value = i + 1;
        nodes[i]->next = NULL;

        if( i > 0 )
        {
            nodes[ i-1 ]->next = nodes[i];
        }
    }

    printRecursively(nodes[0]);
} // end function: main
```

Here is the output from execution of the above code:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: *3. does not perform any undefined behavior*... unless `malloc` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @chqrlie,  The undefined behavior is found in the OPs `main()` function where it is trying to link to a 'node' that does not yet exist,   Sure, the array of pointers is defined, but the values in those pointers are being accessed before being set I.E. undefined behavior

Comment: Yes, the OP's code has multiple cases of undefined behavior, and you do address most of them in your answer, except for `malloc()` failure which you do not test.  So your third claim is not completely accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Your code initializes the `next` pointer of each newly allocated code to an uninitialized value.  Run the loop backwards and make sure you initialize the ast node's `next` pointer to `NULL`.

```
int main(void) {
    struct node *nodes[MAX];
    for (int i = MAX; i-- > 0;) {
        nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        nodes[i]->value = i + 1;
        nodes[i]->next = (i == MAX - 1) ? NULL : nodes[i + 1];
    }
    printRecursively(nodes[0]);

    /* for good style, free the allocated memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        free(nodes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you noted, there is a simple solution with increasing index values and a check for memory allocation failure:

```
int main(void) {
    struct node *nodes[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        nodes[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (nodes[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        nodes[i]->value = i + 1;
        nodes[i]->next = NULL;
        if (i > 0) {
            nodes[i - 1]->next = nodes[i];
        }
    }
    printRecursively(nodes[0]);

    /* for good style, free the allocated memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        free(nodes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if(i!=0){ nodes[i-1]->next=nodes[i]; } I think... its done now..! Thank you very much @chqrlie

Comment: @Maharan: you can do that too but make sure to initialize the `next` member of the newly allocated node to `NULL` then.

Comment: Sure Sure... @chqrlie

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a node, and telling him to point to nodes[i+1], but nodes[i+1] is not already initialized, so it will be equal to
`nodes[i]->next = garbage`

Comment: The array has automatic storage: uninitialized array elements are not necessarily `NULL`. Furthermore, even if the array was global, the behavior would still be undefined because of the last `next` pointer.

Comment: if(i!=0){
   nodes[i-1]->next=nodes[i];
  }
I think... its done now..! Thank you very much @bennes

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems with your code.

The first one is that when you are creating the node `nodes[i]` `nodes[i+1]` has indeterminate value.

Thus this statement

```
nodes[i]->next = nodes[i + 1];
```

results in undefined behavior when you will try to access a node using the data member `next`.

The second one is that the loop trying to access the memory beyond the array when the index `i`  is equal to `MAX-1`.

The third one is you do not set the data member `next` of the last node to `NULL`.

To resolve the problems you should declare the array with `MAX+!` elements and allocate nodes starting from the end of the array.

Also you should free all the allocated memory.

And according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void printRecursively( struct node *start )
{
    if ( start != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", start->value );
        printRecursively( start->next );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node * nodes[MAX + 1];

    int i = MAX;
    nodes[i] = NULL;

    for ( ; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        nodes[i-1] = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        nodes[i-1]->value = i;
        nodes[i-1]->next = nodes[i];
    }

    printRecursively( nodes[0] );

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) free( nodes[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```